# Match different variant of a word using regex Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am splitting sentences at individual space characters, and then matching these terms against keys of hashes. I am getting matches only if the terms are 100% similar, and I am struggling to find a perfect regex that could match several occurrences of the same word. Eg. Let us consider I have a term 'antagon' now it perfectly matches with the term 'antagon' but fails to match with antagonists, antagonistic or pre-antagonistic, hydro-antagonist etc. Also I need a regex to match occurrences of words like MCF-7 with MCF7 or MC-F7 silencing the effect of special characters and so on.

This is the code that I have till now; thr commented part is where I am struggling.

(Note: Terms in the hash are stemmed to root form of a word).

```
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use Drug;
    use Stop;
    open IN,  "sample.txt"   or die "cannot find sample";
    open OUT, ">sample1.txt" or die "cannot find sample";

    while (<IN>) {
        chomp $_;
        my $flag = 0;
        my $line = lc $_;
        my @full = ();
        if ( $line =~ /<Sentence.*>(.*)<\/Sentence>/i ) {
            my $string = $1;
            chomp $string;
            $string =~ s/,/ , /g;
            $string =~ s/\./ \. /g;
            $string =~ s/;/ ; /g;
            $string =~ s/\(/ ( /g;
            $string =~ s/\)/ )/g;
            $string =~ s/\:/ : /g;
            $string =~ s/\::/ :: )/g;
            my @array = split / /, $string;

            foreach my $word (@array) {
                chomp $word;
                if ( $word =~ /\,|\;|\.|\(|\)/g ) {
                    push( @full, $word );
                }
                if ( $Stop_words{$word} ) {
                    push( @full, $word );
                }

                if ( $Values{$word} ) {
                    my $term = "<Drug>$word<\/Drug>";
                    push( @full, $term );
                }
                else {
                    push( @full, $word );
                }

                # if($word=~/.*\Q$Values{$word}\E/i)#Changed this
                # {
                # $term="<Drug>$word</$Drug>";
                # print $term,"\n";
                # push(@full,$term);
                # }
            }
        }
        my $mod_str = join( " ", @full );
        print OUT $mod_str, "\n";
    }
```

Comment: You should try to make your question more concise.

Comment: Provide your `sample.txt` please.  Generally for your "special characters" case the easiest way is to simply strip them out of the input before you begin.

Comment: The sample.txt file is scientific text file, I cannot strip these characters as that would change meaning of few terms

Comment: @TLP : Let let me know which part is not clear to you

Comment: I don't think regular expressions can do what you want. Sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Consider [String::Compare](http://p3rl.org/String::Compare).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need a regex to match occurances of words like MCF-7 with MCF7 or
>   MC-F7

The most straightforward approach is just to strip out the hyphenss i.e.

```
my $ignore_these = "[-_']"
$word =~ s{$ignore_these}{}g;
```

I am not sure what is stored in your Value hash, so its hard to tell what you expect to happen

```
if($word=~/.*\Q$Values{$word}\E/i)
```

However, the kind of thing I imagin you want is (simplified your code somewhat)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use 5.10.0;
use Data::Dumper;

while (<>) {
    chomp $_;
    my $flag = 0;
    my $line = lc $_;
    my @full = ();
    if ( $line =~ /<Sentence.*>(.*)<\/Sentence>/i ) {
        my $string = $1;
        chomp $string;
        $string =~ s/([,\.;\(\)\:])/ $1 /g; # squished these together 
        $string =~ s/\:\:/ :: )/g;          # typo in original
        my @array = split /\s+/, $string;   # split on one /or more/ spaces

        foreach my $word (@array) {
            chomp $word;
                        my $term=$word;
                        my $word_chars = "[\\w\\-_']";
                        my $word_part  = "antagon";
                        if ($word =~ m{$word_chars*?$word_part$word_chars+}) {
                            $term="<Drug>$word</Drug>";
                        }
                        push(@full,$term); # push 

        }
    }
    my $mod_str = join( " ", @full );
        say "<Sentence>$mod_str</Sentence>";
}
```

This gives me the following output, which is my best guess at what you expect:

```
$ cat tmp.txt 
<Sentence>This in antagonizing the antagonist's antagonism pre-antagonistically.</Sentence>
$ cat tmp.txt | perl x.pl
<Sentence>this in <Drug>antagonizing</Drug> the <Drug>antagonist's</Drug> <Drug>antagonism</Drug> <Drug>pre-antagonistically</Drug> .</Sentence>
$
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -ne '$things{$1}++while s/([^ ;.,!?]*?antagon[^ ;.,!?]++)//;END{print "$_\n" for sort keys %things}' FILENAME
```

If the file contains the following:

```
he was an antagonist
antagonize is a verb
why are you antagonizing her?
this is an alpha-antagonist
```

This will return:

```
alpha-antagonist
antagonist
antagonize
antagonizing
```

Below is the a regular (not one-liner) version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
open my $in, "<", "sample.txt" or die "could not open sample.txt for reading!";
open my $out, ">", "sample1.txt" or die "could not open sample1.txt for writing!";

my %things;

while (<$in>){
    $things{$1}++ while s/([^ ;.,!?]*?antagon[^ ;.,!?]++)//
}

print $out "$_\n" for sort keys %things;
```

Comment: if($word=~/\b\Q$Values{$word}\E(\w++)\b/i) Matches everything

Comment: Explain what you mean.  I'm not sure what you want.  I just updated my code some.  I am about to make it handle commas and such correctly.

Comment: Can you update that in my code at the commented part?. What you explained above is exactly what I want.

Comment: The code should work as intended now.  I assumed you are running from a terminal that allows you to do `perl -ne`.  You must replace `FILENAME` with the name of the file to examine.  If you are not operating from a terminal to run the command as I have written, tell me and I will rewrite it in a different form.

Comment: I am not running from terminal. Please could you please update at the commented region.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take another look at your assumptions on your approach. What it sounds like to me is that you are looking for words which are within a certain distance of a list of words. Take a look at the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) formula to see if this is something you want. Be aware, however, that computing this might take exponential time.

Comment: I am just trying to find a regex to match different form of same words, like if my hash key is synerg, it should match terms like synergistic, anti-synergy.

Comment: Well, continuing from one of your original thoughts, you could strip out special characters with replacing every match of `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` with the empty string.


Furthermore, you could do a search using your key (assuming your key might be the short/general version of what might be a longer word) against the string you're currently testing. If there is a match (key is in test string), then you've likely found an occurrence.

Comment: +1 for metioning the Levenshtein distance. I had good results for a different task using [String::Compare](http://p3rl.org/String::Compare).

Comment: Striping terms or replacing say with spaces, will change the term meaning. Eg: MC-F7. If I do this MC will be one term while F7 would be other term. Which makes key from hash (MCF7) difficult to match

Comment: Then regular expression are not the right tool for this task.

Comment: Or, don't replace with a space, replace with the empty string: "" MC-F7 becomes MCF7 which is the key.

Comment: @netinept: This is just a sample case I have, stripping would make it tough as there are terms like drug-antigen, which would become drugantigen and it is not possible to match

Comment: @Pink I'm not sure if you understand how matching works. Given the key, "antigen" and a list of possible matches: `["drug-antigen","anti-generative","BLAHantigenBLAH"]`, after the replace function as mentioned, the new list of possible matches would be `["drugantigen","antigenerative","BLAHantigenBLAH"]`. This would cause  the key to match (this is a "global" match) on each of the three items.

Comment: @Pink `drug-antigen` wouldn't match with the solution you just accepted, either, because it requires the string to contain `antagon`.